# Can eMMC (v4.5 or v5.1) NC balls used for routing?

Tags: memory, emmc

I've seen in the various JEDEC documents and datasheet from different memory manufacturers that the NC (no connection) balls are not connected internally to anything

- EDIT: [datasheet example](https://www.macronix.com/Lists/Datasheet/Attachments/7963/MX52LM04A11,%203V,%204GB,%20v1.3.pdf), look at bottom of page 8
- EDIT2: [datasheet example number 2](https://www.issi.com/WW/pdf/IS21_22ES08G.pdf), page 9.
  Also a little snapshot from a datasheet that isn't publicly available:
  [image]

Despite this, in those documents it is said that the NC balls can be tied to GND or left floating.

What if I use them to route the signals outside the package as shown [here](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Octavo%20PDFs/DesigningForFlexibilityAround-EMMC.pdf)? Would there be any complications?

Comment: Did you end up using them for routing? While some manufacturers don't mention explicitly the NC pin internal connection, it seems generally accepted that these pins can be used to ease routing for eMMC.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your linked datasheet, it does not say what you said it says. The datasheet says:

> 1. NC: NOT Connected, shall be connected to ground or left floating.
> 2. RFU: Reserved for Future Use, shall be left floating for future use.

The important difference is that the datasheet says **shall** rather than **can**. When you see the word "shall" you should interpret that as meaning **must**, not "can".

Unless the data sheet for the exact part you are using states that you can route through an NC then you should not do it. Don't try to make assumptions about what "NC" really means.

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply. I added one more EDIT with more examples from other datasheets. I've also searched in JEDEC JESD84-B51 except that there they don't mention additional pins like the NC ones.